# How to delete ALL comments from certain category in Wordpress database?

Tags: sql, comments

I'm trying to delete all comments from posts in a certain category in a Wordpress database.

The Wordpress database is rather complicated so this must be probably some join of `wp_posts`, `wp_comments` and `wp_term_relationships` as the categories are not stored with neither posts nor comments.

How can I do this? I'm struggling to come up with a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wordpress database seems fairly straight forward and is extremely well documented:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

It seems to me that all the category information is stored in the table **wp_term_relationships**. So you should select from the comments table, join it with the posts table and then the term_relationships table in order to get the category for each comment.

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_comments
WHERE comment_post_ID
IN (

SELECT c.object_id
FROM wp_terms a, wp_term_taxonomy b, wp_term_relationships c
WHERE a.name = 'my_category_slug'
AND b.term_id = a.term_id
AND b.taxonomy = 'category'
AND c.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id
)
```

Comment: i found this code on wordpress forums too but it doesnt work well, same problem, it lists comments from many different categories...

Comment: ok the problem here is its not category slug isntead of "'my_category_slug'" but actual name, which is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I can provide you the `delete` command from `join` tables. Then you need to add the relevant tables and columns though

```
-- using LEFT JOIN

DELETE  x.*
FROM    table1 AS x 
LEFT JOIN
        table2 AS y 
ON      y.id = x.id

-- using IN:

DELETE  
FROM    table1 AS x
WHERE   id IN
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    table2
        )
```

Usually `left join` is faster than `in`. Looking at that `ERD`, you would also better watch out for any `foreign key` relationships if `delete on cascade` is not implemented.